# dynamic tabcontrol in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

can we implement dynamic tab controls in ASP.Net MVC. If so can any one provide me a link to any related resources.

I looked at jquery tab controls but i was not able to find out dynamic tab controls.

for example if I have a drop down list for names of a customers i should be able to show different orders for that one customers in tabs. i don't know how may orders does a customer have( In my application i don't need more that 4 tabs any way

Comment: Define "dynamic tab controls." You can implement just about anything you want.

Comment: "dynamic" in what sense?  the tabs are just actions on the same controller, if that is what you are asking. if you want to do that without reloading the page, then you want to use ajax to pass requests back and forth to the controller.

Comment: for example if I have a drop down list for names of a customers i should be able to show different orders for that one customers in tabs. i don't know how may orders does a customer have( In my application i don't need more that 4 tabs any way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jquery tab ui is dynamic in the sense that you can add new divs to the page and have the tabs extension display this as a new tab.

[Manipulation of tab control](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation)

If you want this manipulation to be perisisted you could then make a jquery ajax call to a controller action passing back the new tab details and then save this to a db.

When the page is rendered in MVC you can control the outputted HTML and then teh tab extention is simply applied to the top level div so in this sense it is also dynamic.